# Add thousands of columns using if_else/summarize in dplyr chain?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have data comprised of state-group observations (ie fast food companies in states). Multiple observations of the same state-group in the same year are common. Each row contains a value (ie number of new fast food franchises). I aggregate this data into state-group-years then need to create a dichotomous indicator for whether each state-group pair reached a certain threshold of franchises in each year. After that, I need to aggregate the data to the state-year level and create a dichotomous indicator that measures whether *any* state-group pair passed the threshold in that year.

I am using dplyr to do this and the code below works perfectly. However, I am hard coding the different thresholds (25 franchises, 50 franchises, etc.) and would like a solution where I could create variables for an aribrtrary number of thresholds - such as all all number between 25:1000. Is there a straightforward and programmatic way to do this? I have tried for loops in the dplyr chain but struggle with how to add the new variables with principled names (the name should include the threshold for easy referencing in later code). Thanks for any help!

note: feel free to edit the title/question to be more clear.

```
x <- data.frame("state" = c(rep("mi",12),
                            rep("tx",12)),
                "group" = c(rep("grp1",6),rep("grp2",6),
                            rep("grp3",6),rep("grp4",6)), 
                "year"  = c(rep(1990,3),rep(1991,3),rep(1992,3),rep(1993,3),
                            rep(1990,3),rep(1991,3),rep(1992,3),rep(1993,3)),
                "value" = c(seq(20,1200, by = 100),
                            seq(20,2400, by = 200)))

x_agg <- x %>%
  group_by(state, group, year) %>%
  summarise(value_tot = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(val20   = ifelse(value_tot >= 20,   yes = 1, no = 0),
         val50   = ifelse(value_tot >= 50,   yes = 1, no = 0),
         val100  = ifelse(value_tot >= 100,  yes = 1, no = 0),
         val250  = ifelse(value_tot >= 250,  yes = 1, no = 0),
         val500  = ifelse(value_tot >= 500,  yes = 1, no = 0),
         val750  = ifelse(value_tot >= 750,  yes = 1, no = 0),
         val1000 = ifelse(value_tot >= 1000, yes = 1, no = 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(state, year) %>%
  summarise(val20   = as.numeric(any(val20 == 1)),
            val50   = as.numeric(any(val50 == 1)),
            val100  = as.numeric(any(val100 == 1)),
            val250  = as.numeric(any(val250 == 1)),
            val500  = as.numeric(any(val500 == 1)),
            val750  = as.numeric(any(val750 == 1)),
            val1000 = as.numeric(any(val1000 == 1)),) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `lapply` to create a list of function and `mutate_at` to apply them all. I start with the `x` you provide. Simply change `seq_val` to have the sequence of numbers you want to test.

```
seq_val <- seq(1000, 10000, by = 1000)
val_funs <- lapply(seq_val, function(x) (function(a) as.integer(a >= x)))
names(val_funs) <- paste0("val", seq_val)

agg1 <- x %>%
  group_by(state, group, year) %>%
  summarise(value_tot = sum(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_at(
    "value_tot", 
    val_funs
  )
```

`agg1` outputs:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 14
  state group  year value_tot val1000 val2000 val3000 val4000 val5000 val6000
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 mi    grp1   1990       360       0       0       0       0       0       0
2 mi    grp1   1991      1260       1       0       0       0       0       0
3 mi    grp2   1992      2160       1       1       0       0       0       0
4 mi    grp2   1993      3060       1       1       1       0       0       0
5 tx    grp3   1990       660       0       0       0       0       0       0
6 tx    grp3   1991      2460       1       1       0       0       0       0
7 tx    grp4   1992      4260       1       1       1       1       0       0
8 tx    grp4   1993      6060       1       1       1       1       1       1
# … with 4 more variables: val7000 <dbl>, val8000 <dbl>, val9000 <dbl>,
#   val10000 <dbl>
```

Then `summarise_at` with `any`

```
agg1 %>%
  group_by(state, year) %>%
  summarise_at(
    vars(matches("val[^u]")),
    function(x) as.numeric(any(x == 1))
  )
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 12
# Groups:   state [2]
  state  year val1000 val2000 val3000 val4000 val5000 val6000 val7000 val8000
  <fct> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 mi     1990       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
2 mi     1991       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3 mi     1992       1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
4 mi     1993       1       1       1       0       0       0       0       0
5 tx     1990       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
6 tx     1991       1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
7 tx     1992       1       1       1       1       0       0       0       0
8 tx     1993       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
# … with 2 more variables: val9000 <dbl>, val10000 <dbl>
```

Comment: This might run faster if you `ungroup()` before the first `mutate_at`. Also, you don't need the `ifelse`, but can use something like `as.integer(a >= x)`. Otherwise great use of `mutate_at`!

Comment: This is great@ Thanks - accepted. Fast and easy to understand solution. Really appreciate the help. This approach would never have occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way for you. After aggregating the data, I redefined groups by adding `year` again. Then, for each group, I wanted to run logical checks. There is one specific value_tot value in each group. I had logical checks against this value using the criterion values (i.e., 20, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, and 1000). The returned logical values are converted to numbers and added to a data frame with the criterion values. By this time, you have a data frame in each cell of `foo`. I used unnest and created the result. It is still in a long format. Given you want a wide-format data, I used `pivot_wider()` in the end.

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>%
group_by(state, group, year) %>%
summarise(value_tot = sum(value)) %>%
group_by(year, add = TRUE) %>% 
mutate(foo = list(tibble(check = sapply(c(20, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000),
                                        function(x) as.numeric(value_tot >= x)),
                         category = c(20, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000)))) %>% 
unnest(foo) %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = state:year, names_from = category, names_prefix = "val",
            values_from = "check")

  state group  year val20 val50 val100 val250 val500 val750 val1000
  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 mi    grp1   1990     1     1      1      1      0      0       0
2 mi    grp1   1991     1     1      1      1      1      1       1
3 mi    grp2   1992     1     1      1      1      1      1       1
4 mi    grp2   1993     1     1      1      1      1      1       1
5 tx    grp3   1990     1     1      1      1      1      0       0
6 tx    grp3   1991     1     1      1      1      1      1       1
7 tx    grp4   1992     1     1      1      1      1      1       1
8 tx    grp4   1993     1     1      1      1      1      1       1
```

Comment: May be `findInterval` can be used

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. I have never used pivot_wider so this was great. I upvoted but accepted the answer that came in first.

Comment: @akrun I did not have time to consider your idea till this evening here. Now I am thinking about what you mean. `findInterval()` requires two numerical vectors, right? So one vector would be `value_tot`. The other would be one containing 20, 50, 100, and so on. value <- 100; criteria <- c(25, 50, 100, 200, 300); findInterval(value, criteria) This gives me 3. I am having a hard time to find how to use this information. Can you help me when you have a bit of spare time?

Comment: I didn't test it, but was thinking that it may be useful here.  May be not

Comment: @akrun I will further think about this over this weekend. Off to bed now. Hope you rock hard here. :)

Comment: @akrun I just used `findInterval()`. I was thinking today that, as far as I see, findInterval() does work. But it may require a bit more coding. As I mentioned last time, I can return an integer. I think I can create a sequence of 1 using this integer in seq(), for example. But the thing is the sapply() in my idea is actually doing the same thing. It is probably saving typing to some extent. Can you think of any other way to exploit findIntervals() here? If there is any idea, please let me know.

Comment: @jazzurro Sure, will let you know

Answer (score 1):

I would try like here with `lapply` and `join` on multiples tables. In `treshold` you define columns.

```
library("dplyr")

x <- data.frame("state" = c(rep("mi",12),
                            rep("tx",12)),
                "group" = c(rep("grp1",6),rep("grp2",6),
                            rep("grp3",6),rep("grp4",6)), 
                "year"  = c(rep(1990,3),rep(1991,3),rep(1992,3),rep(1993,3),
                            rep(1990,3),rep(1991,3),rep(1992,3),rep(1993,3)),
                "value" = c(seq(20,1200, by = 100),
                            seq(20,2400, by = 200)))

treshold <- c(20, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000)

lapply(as.list(treshold), function(tres){

  name <- paste0("val", tres)

  x %>% 
    group_by(state, group, year) %>% 
    summarise(value_tot = sum(value)) %>%
    mutate(!!name := as.integer(value_tot >= tres)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    group_by(state, year) %>%
    summarise(!!name := as.numeric(any(!!sym(name) == 1)))

}) %>% Reduce(function(d1, d2) full_join(d1, d2, by = c("state", "year")), .)
```

Comment: Nice answer! No need for `ungroup` then `group_by`, although you could move `ungroup` one line up (before `mutate`). I'm wondering whether you could just bind the new column, instead of doing a more costly `full_join`.

Comment: I agree with `group_by` - I've just copied it from original example but - as you've said - it is unnecessery. Problem with binding is that it repeats all columns. You can probably try to do it (with for example exeption for the first element of `list` to keep those two columns only once). If data is large it is probably worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
valueExceeds <- function(df, n){
    variableName <- paste0("val", n)
    df %>%
        group_by(state, group, year) %>%
        summarise(value_tot = sum(value)) %>%
        mutate(!!variableName := as.integer(value_tot >= n))
}

x %>%
    valueExceeds(20)
```

outputs this

```
  state group  year value_tot val20
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
1 mi    grp1   1990       360     1
2 mi    grp1   1991      1260     1
3 mi    grp2   1992      2160     1
4 mi    grp2   1993      3060     1
5 tx    grp3   1990       660     1
6 tx    grp3   1991      2460     1
7 tx    grp4   1992      4260     1
8 tx    grp4   1993      6060     1
```